Non-toxic light lube for components
I'm trying to minimize my exposure to toxic chemicals when riding or fiddling with my bike. To this end I wax my chain in paraffin wax and wear nitrile gloves when handling grease (which ideally stays inside the bike).
However, for components that are more exposed and I touch on a regular basis (brake calipers/levers, cables, derailleur springs, etc.), I'm having trouble finding a non-toxic lube. Do folks have suggestions?
I've seen Green Oil but I'm currently avoiding them for political reasons.

Baby oil smells nice and is supposedly ok for use on babies so safe there. It's a mineral oil so will offer some amount of lubrication and protection.

Have you considered a lanolin based product like Lanoguard?

Voted to reopen because it is entirely possible to answer the question using general product categories. It is not necessary to recommend specific brands and/or products.

Many companies offer food-safe lubricating oils. Here’s an illustrative example: https://www.super-lube.com/h-3-lightweight-oil-60004
Now, I am not completely sure whether something being food safe necessarily implies that it is safe for skin contact, but out of common sense I would strongly imagine that to be the case.

Is it typical for bicycle mechanics (amateur or professional) to use lubes and greases not specifically designed or marketed towards bicycles?

@LucasMyers As a professional bicycle mechanic, I can say that the best product for the job is the best choice. For larger pack sizes, automotive products are best value. Marine products can offer better corrosion protection. Where personal safety is your concern, you can use what you know about a given product (which could be from any industry) and adapt the use for your purpose. Maybe lubrication is not quite so good, or reapplication is more frequent, but we all choose what is most important to us.

@LucasMyers A: a lot of (most?) bicycle lubricants are just rebranded products from other industries, and B: the acceptable range of lubricant properties for your application is extremely broad. There’s a few cases where you truly want the right stuff (eg. suspension grease, internal hub gear oil), but in other cases it matters very little.
